# ipython is killing while ipykernel is dead, what should i do?

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have been trying to import a csv file through pandas, the file is huge and showed resistance in pandas what is an alternate solution? I have installed conda3.6 and Path is given in ~./bashrc in ubuntu 16.04 version.

I am using ubuntu in virtual environment, is there any possibility that support on virtual machine is limited to upload massive files. The file .csv contains 500MB data.

Have tried all options deleted ipython and installed it again and same for ipykernel too, but didn't get any improvement.

ipython killing the file upload error

[image: ipython killing the file upload error].

Image showing dead kernel which is repeating again and again in jupyter notebook

[image: Image showing dead kernel which is repeating again and again in jupyter notebook]

Comment: it is better to include your snapshots in the question as soon as you get the privilege

Comment: Stack overflow was unable to upload my images because i am quite new user to this platform. As soon as i get my points covered i will add direct images, thanks for the suggestion.